# Asynchronous return issue

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I'm trying to write a function which i can use in an if statement for logic. I've used callback functions to avoid having undefined response due to the asynchronous nature of Javascript. Am i going about this all wrong? is there a better way?

```
if(emailExists(Email, someCallback)){
  //email does exist, do stuff
}
```

Basically i just want a function to tell me if an email exists in my database to return true, But even with all the precaution i took i'm still getting undefined when i run this code.

```
function someCallback(e){
  console.log(e);
  return e;
}

function emailExists(input, callback) {
  pg.connect(conString, function(err, client, done){
    //Connect to database

    client.query('select email from users', function(err, result){
      //select all emails from database

      var tempArray = [];
      for(var x = 0; x < result.rows.length; x++){
        tempArray.push(result.rows[x].email)
      } //create array of emails

      callback(tempArray.includes(input));
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: With your current setup, you will have to handle the result using the callback method, not in your main code block.  Since `emailExists` does not return a value it will never enter that `if` block.

Comment: The variables `input` and `email` should be the same variable. You are checking for an email that is `undefined`.

Comment: isnt that what the someCallback function is for?

Comment: `tempArray.includes(email)` already returns a boolean. You don’t need the conditional operator at all.

Comment: You need to perform the `if` in the callback function.

Comment: `if(emailExists(Email, someCallback)){
  //email does exist, do stuff
}` might be either `if(emailExists(Email, someCallback))` or `if(emailExists(Email, function(){
  //email does exist, do stuff
})`

Comment: @Xufox oh right, oops. but regardless my console currently still prints undefined. and the console.log in the callback function returns true.

Comment: you `//email does exist, do stuff` needs to be in the call back.

Comment: Why don't you use a **promise**?. This helps: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/231/promises#t=201705302239008838257

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I  would recommend using a Promise instead, that makes working with async much more convenient. I didn't use pg-js before and don't know if it does support promises by itself - if so, you can simply use the promise returned by it; if not, below code will work for you:

```
function emailExists(input) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        pg.connect(conString, function (err, client, done) {
            client.query('select email from users', function (err, result) {
                var tempArray = [];
                for (var x = 0; x < result.rows.length; x ++) {
                    tempArray.push(result.rows[x].email)
                }
                resolve(tempArray.includes(email));
            });
        });
    });
}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
emailExists("foo@bar.baz")
    .then(exists => {
        if (exists) {
            // email exists
        } else {
            // not
        }
    });
```

Comment: Holy crap that work wonders, So do you recommand using promises instead of callbacks whenever dealing with async? I didnt use a promise because i wasnt familiar with how to write it and i'm pretty new to async programming.

Comment: You should use them, yeah. Luckily, they aren't very complicated to be implemented too, so you should get familiar with promises quite quickly. @user3307553

Comment: @user3307553 The easiest is to go for [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) from the start.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put your if statement in the callback.

```
emailExists(Email, function(hasMail){
    if(hasMail){
        //email does exist, do stuff
     }
 });
```

Promise would be good but not required.